# Practical Application of Genetic Algorithm

Tags: algorithm, genetic-algorithm

I am doing a project work on **non dominated sorting** or **multivector sorting** algorithm, which is used in **selection** part of a **genetic algorithm**. I have searched on web but still I dont know about practical applications of **Genetic Algorithm**.  I only know that it is used in **Testing**, but I dont know how it works there. Can you suggest some practical applications of **Genetic Algorithms**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GAs are a great way of finding good solutions to problems where the search space is huge and finding the exact optimal solution is very hard. They are good at hill-climbing and can be used to generate a candidate set from different regions of the solution space which can then by further optimized by algorithms which excel at local optimization. In some cases they come up with solutions which would be very hard for a human to visualize up front.

This is an interesting list of [GA applications](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_genetic_algorithm_applications).

Answer (score 5):

Genetic algorithms are great for [feature selection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feature_selection) used by machine learning algorithms.

Many times, there are just too many features in the data set, which makes it too noisy, so we sometimes handle this by reducing the dimensionality of the problem, by selecting only a subset of the features. For this purposes - Genetic Algorithms seems to work great in many cases (Empirically), and its usage is wide both in research and in real world applications that have very high dimensionality.

For example: text analyzis, with the [bag of words model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bag_of_words_model): Sometimes we want to use only a subset of the words, and not all of them, so we use a feature selection algorithm for it, and GA is one of them.

Answer (score 1):

You can use GA for community detection 
http://www.springerlink.com/content/u570144q73322970/

Take a real life network, for example, you could take your own facebook friend network, where nodes are friends, edges between friends would denote a friendship link. When you run a community detection algorithm, you would notice that the algorithm makes clusters which separate different groups in your friends, like a high school group, a college group, a job group, a family group and so on.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how practical this is but I used it for [sudoku generation](http://anthony-tresontani.github.com/Python/2012/12/31/sudoku-generator-with-genetic/)